# Downloading a file using internet explorer credentials in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to download a file in VB.net from a website that requires credentials, all my users have their credentials to this website saved in their IE settings.
Is there a way to download a file from this website using the IE credentials? I'm trying to avoid from asking my users for their credentials.

thanks.

Edit: I need to download many files, so i need a way to download the files programmatically.

Comment: Is it a desktop application that you are writing?

Comment: yes, its a desktop application written in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

just invoke this command from Process.Start:

```
explorer http://www......
```

this only works if you have the full url of the file you want to download. In case the default browser is not `IE` you should replace `explorer` with `iexplore`

Comment: this will open an internet explorer window, i need to download the file programmatically since i have many file do download..

Comment: then I would be surprised if you can grab the cached credentials of IE as it could potentially be a security issue.